# Where array of primitives stored in JVM memory

Tags: java, memory, jvm

JVM memory is divided into:
1. Method Area
2. Heap Area
3. Stack
4. PC Register
5. Native Stack

1. Now suppose I have a class having property of say "int[] dealCodes"(array of int primitive). As per memory management once deal code is initialized, there would be contiguous memory allocation of (total_elements * 4 bytes) in memory. So if array size is 10 then there will be 40 bytes allocation in JVM memory.

   My question is in which area this 40 bytes will be allocated (heap or stack)?

   My understanding about array is: it's just like any other object and resides under heap area but don't know about primitives to which array points to.
2. Also want to know about similar scenario when array holds references (e.g. array of type Employees). I think in this case, everything will be in heap area. As these are references then array will hold 4 bytes for each reference (32 bit system) and these references will point to objects of varying size. 
   Array memory allocation will be calculated on basis of reference size not object size.

Please help me to get clarity on above 2 points.

Comment: Arrays are objects so it's on the heap

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Objects are always Heap allocated so your `dealCodes` will be
 allocated there only but the total memory allocated is more than 40 bytes.

```
12 bytes (Header) + 4 bytes (Length of Array) + 40 bytes (4 bytes * 10 ints) = 56 bytes
```

Same thing applies to an array of `Employee` objects as well except that each array element is now a reference to Employee object, so the `Shallow Heap` occupied by employees array is still 56 bytes while the `Retained Heap` depends on the size of each Employee object.

You can use `VisualVM` in JDK_HOME/bin directory to take a snapshot of your program/application, see the memory occupied by each object, both shallow and retained heap sizes.

Comment: Arkantos & Clément... thanks to both of you for clarifying my doubt...crystal clear explanation.... :-)

Answer (score 2):

> 1. My question is in which area this 40 bytes will be allocated (heap or stack)?

Heap allocated.

Please note that more than 40 bytes will be allocated since there is some overhead for the Object header + the length attribute of the array.

If you are interested in this, you can play with [Java Object Layout](http://openjdk.java.net/projects/code-tools/jol/)

> Also want to know about similar scenario when array holds references (e.g. array of type Employees). I think in this case, everything will be in heap area. As these are references then array will hold 4 bytes for each reference (32 bit system) and these references will point to objects of varying size.

Exactly.

Size of the references depends on the architecture, 32 bits VS 64 bits, and the possible usage of [CompressedOops](https://wikis.oracle.com/display/HotSpotInternals/CompressedOops).

Comment: Starting from JDK7, CompressedOops are enabled by default and they work only for heaps less than 32 GBs, pointed to be noted :)

Comment: Yes it is enabled by default for most usages, but memory footprint still depends on CompressedOops usage :)

Comment: True, until Java 6, that flag actually helped reduce object header sizes in 64-bit JVM but now (Java 7 & 8) you don't have to worry about it as long as we're in that 32GB limit on a 64 bit VM :)

Comment: Arkantos & Clément... thanks to both of you for clarifying my doubt...crystal clear explanation.... :-)